# Warnings with PublishAot and deserializing json System.Text.Json in .NET 8.0.100

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json, c#-8.0

I'm getting multiple warning about deserializing json with System.Text.Json .NET 8.0.100

How would I get rid of the warnings? I do want to note that the current code works, but I want to get rid of the warnings. Or can I keep and ignore the warnings when I run dotnet publish?

Warning 1: Using member 'System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(Stream, Type, JsonSerializerOptions)' which has 'RequiresDynamicCodeAttribute' can break functionality when AOT compiling. JSON serialization and deserialization might require types that cannot be statically analyzed and might need runtime code generation. Use System.Text.Json source generation for native AOT applications.

Warning 2: Using member 'System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(Stream, Type, JsonSerializerOptions)' which has 'RequiresUnreferencedCodeAttribute' can break functionality when trimming application code. JSON serialization and deserialization might require types that cannot be statically analyzed. Use the overload that takes a JsonTypeInfo or JsonSerializerContext, or make sure all of the required types are preserved.

I have

`<PublishAot>true</PublishAot>`

Added in my .csproj file

My code generating the warnings in GetConfig.cs is:

GetConfig.cs

```
using System.Text.Json;

namespace LamboRizzBot
{
    public class GetConfig
    {
        private readonly Logger log;

        public GetConfig()
        {
            var makelogger = new Logger("GetConfig");
            log = makelogger;
        }

        public TwitchInfo ParseConfig()
        {
            try
            {
                string filename = "config.json";

                using var stream = File.OpenRead(filename);
                var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
                var context = new JsonContext(options);
                var info = context.GetTypeInfo(typeof(TwitchInfo));

                TwitchInfo result = (TwitchInfo)JsonSerializer.Deserialize(stream, typeof(TwitchInfo), options)!; // The 2 warnings are coming from this line
                return result;
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException)
            {
                log.Error("No config.json found");
                throw;
            }
            catch (JsonException)
            {
                log.Error("Could not parse config.json. Please check your config.json configuration");
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

TwitchInfo.cs:

```
namespace LamboRizzBot
{
    [JsonSerializable(typeof(TwitchInfo))]
    public partial class JsonContext : JsonSerializerContext
    {
    }

    public class TwitchInfo
    {
        public string Nickname { get; set; }
        public string OAuth { get; set; }
        public string[]? Channels { get; set; }
        public TwitchInfo()
        {
            Nickname = string.Empty;
            OAuth = string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

config.json:

```
    "Nickname": "nickname",
    "OAuth": "mytoken",
    "Channels": ["channel1", "channel2"]
}
```

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/system-text-json-in-dotnet-8/#disabling-reflection-defaults